# Record a comment before cancelling a jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have provided access to users to abort the running jobs. But, before aborting a job it should prompt and record some additional information from user. To track why they are aborting a build.

Do we have any plugins to do this ?

Thanks,
Ras Dama.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same option but found currently it is not available.

[Require user to enter reason for manual build abortion](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23367)

Above link is the feature request submitted already to Jenkins but it is still in Open state.

So suggestion is, **if you go the page for a particular build, you can click "Edit build information" and add comments for the build**. This is what i do.

Comment: Unlike this we need something to prompt user to enter comment, whenever he cancel a build. It should be forceful.